# DOM Manipulation After .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

Trying to use [Rainbow.js](http://craig.is/making/rainbows/) for syntax highlighting. I have a pagination navigation that, when being clicked, loads the page (#page2) into the `body`. It works great, but when I call Rainbow.color() (which searches the DOM for syntax inside pre-defined `pre` tags), it fails to color it. When the page first loads, I call this event:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    /* Act on the event */
    Rainbow.color();
});
```

And it works just fine! But when I call this function, Rainbow.color() does not highlight anything!

```
$('.pure-paginator .pure-button').on('click', function () {
    $('#content').load('html.html ' + $(this).attr('href'));
    Rainbow.color();
});
```

Help is appreciated, let me know if you need more code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ajax is async. Put your call in the ajax callback:

```
$('.pure-paginator .pure-button').on('click', function () {
    $('#content').load('html.html ' + $(this).attr('href'), function() {
        Rainbow.color();
    });
});
```

Comment: Was it really this easy? Woooooww... haha. I didn't know there was a second field for the .load() method. Thanks!

Comment: I was looking at the .load documentation, I just thought it was only useful for console.log for testing purposes.

Comment: Ah, no, in general (and here in particular), a callback is a function to be run after the task (whether be an ajax call, an animation, etc) has completed.